# Metric Topology: Collection of $B_d(x,\epsilon)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> **Theorem20.1.** Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Defined $\bar d-:X×X→R\ $ by the equation
>   $\bar d  ( x , y ) = \min \{ d ( x , y ) , 1 \}$ . Then $\bar d$  is a metric that induces the same topology as $d$.

Does it mean that $\bar d$ "can" induce the same topology as $d$ or always induces the same topology as $d$?

or for the given metric, there always exists unique topology?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that a metric always induces a topology, but it is not true that the topology is unique to that metric, i.e., different metrics may induce the same topology.

For the sake of making this more clear, let's make the following definition:  For a metric $d$ on $X$, we say a subset $U$ of $X$ is $d$-open if for each $x_0\in U$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $x\in X$ and $d(x,x_0)<\varepsilon$, then $x\in U$.  The collection of $d$-open subsets is then called the topology induced by $d$.

Thus, when we say that $\overline d$ induces the same topology as $d$, we mean that the collection of $\overline d$-open subsets of $X$ is precisely the collection of $d$-open subsets.

Comment: At the following lemma, then T, T' is not unique?

Lemma 20.2. Let d and d  be two metrics on the set X; let T and T'  be the topologies they induce, respectively. Then T   is finer than T' if and only if for each x in X and each > 0, there exists a δ > 0 such that
Bd (x,δ)⊂Bd(x, ).

Comment: I'm sorry, I was ambiguous.  When I said the topology was not unique, I meant it was not unique *to that metric*.